# Issue in the mobile View - css

Tags: css, button, mobile

Issue is in the mobile view CSS.

Please go to this site: http://playofpaints.com

I want to move the navigation button a bit towards the right. And increase the width of the logo, Without increasing the height. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation bar have auto with size...

**Try to set the header with;**

```
   .navbar-header {
        float: none;
        display: table-cell !important;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 230px; /* e.g. set 330px */
    }
```

But fixed height size, and increase the width cause image warp.

Comment: HI, Onur.. thanks for the reply.... it didn't work :/.. i want the navigation button to move towards the search icon... and increase the height of the logo...